# Create a slideshow video file from images with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, rubygems, slideshow, rails-activestorage

I am trying to create a video file using [streamio-ffmpeg gem](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg). The images are stored in the `active-storage`.

controller

```
def create_a_video

   require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
   slideshow_transcoder = FFMPEG::Transcoder.new(
   '',
   'slideshow.mp4',
   { resolution: "320x240" },
   input: url_for(Gallery.first.image),
   input_options: { framerate: '1/5' }
   )

   slideshow = slideshow_transcoder.run
end
```

when I run that code, the page keeps loading and nothing happened. Any help?

Comment: What do you have in server log?